# Microsoft Visio 2003 - How to glue/hook a shape to a brainstorming topic branch?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2003

in Microsoft Visio 2003, in brainstorming, I want to glue or hook a shape to a branch, so every time I move that branch, also the shape moves with it automatically.
I have tried to group the two selections but without success.
This is the situation:
[image]

The branch contains the text "approx.", the shape is the "x with tilde". I go to select the two elements to group them, and then when I click on the branch to move the entire group, only the branch moves and not the entire group.

So how to move the entire block of elements? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping won't work here. Select the connector and open its shapesheet.

You will see a cells called EndX and EndY. You need to edit these cells to put a formula guard into them.

The cell will contain something like:
=PAR(PNT(some connection data))

You need to change this to:
=GUARD(PAR(PNT(some connection data)))

This will lock the connection line to the shape.

Downside is that you cannot now disconnect the line from the shape, you will have to edit the line formula again to remove the GUARD.

Comment: Sorry, but, selecting the connector and opening shapesheet I can see for BeginX, BeginY, EndX, EndY the same formula:
   =_WALKGLUE(EndTrigger,BegTrigger,WalkPreference), and adding GUARD to the expression doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Ah, you are using dynamic glue to connect to the shape (i.e. connecting to the centre of the shape so when the shape is moved the connector "walks" around the shape). Try joining the connector to the connection point on the end of the shape.

Comment: No, it doesn't work!